# How can I stop my Android app from getting the MOBILE (REDIRECTED) version of a java.net.URL?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For Wikipedia URLs, this code works in unit tests, but gets different html data in android emulator because it got redirected to Wikipedia's mobile site.  how can I stop that redirect in java?

```
public static String getURLContent(String url) throws Exception {
    URL u = new URL(url);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(u.openStream(), "UTF-8");
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
    String htmlContent = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();
    return htmlContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the setRequestProperty on the HttpURLConnection to prevent from redirecting to mobile version of webpage:

```
public static String getURLContent(String url) throws Exception {
    URL urlObject = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();      
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String htmlContent = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
    return htmlContent;
}
```